# Upgrade to angular 9 Subject now caused ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

After upgrading to Angular version 9, I get a series of  Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'hidden': 'true'. Current value: 'false'.".

This is being cause by the interaction between my OverlayService and the App-Component.  When I use the service to change the value of the overlayOff variable, so my overlay will start.  I get the Error.

This was not the behavior in version 8.x.  I turn off and on the overlay frequently in the project every time I make a change to the DOM from the server.  Suggestion on how to fix this.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div [hidden]="overlayOff" id="overlay">
    <mp-loading marginTop="25"></mp-loading>
  </div>     
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
    @Component({
    // tslint:disable-next-line:component-selector
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

     private overlaySubscription: Subscription;
       overlayOff = true;

     constructor({
       private overlayService: OverlayService) 
     }

     ngOnInit() {
       this.overlaySubscription =      this.overlayService.toggleOverlay
        .subscribe(nextValue => {
           this.overlayOff = (nextValue === undefined) ?  !this.overlayOff : nextValue;
    // console.log('OverlayOff:' + this.overlayOff);
          });
   }

      ngOnDestroy() {
        this.overlaySubscription.unsubscribe();
      }

     }
```

overlay.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

 @Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
  })
 export class OverlayService {
    toggleOverlay: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
    constructor() { }

    overlayOn() {
       // console.log('overlay On');
     this.toggleOverlay.next(false);
    }
    overlayOff() {
       this.toggleOverlay.next(true);
     }
   }
```

Comment: i've been living with this error since angular 7..

Comment: I’d still spend some time understanding the error, unidirectional data flow order of change detection and order checks are made in the template. Whilst irritating the error has taught me a lot. One of the more interesting fixes I’ve seen is wrapping troublesome element with `<div *ngIf=“true”><div>` (not applicable in this case)

Comment: I plan to Andrew, but if anyone has additional research material, I am all ears.  The only reason I think this works is I am updating the variable after the check, therefore mitigating the original problem.  Since the update happens after, no error.

Comment: In my case the solution was to move the logic from ngInit to cunstruct. It solved myproblem, but it cannot help in every situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are much better of using the `async` pipe. This way you don't have to use subscribe at all

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div [hidden]="overlayOff$ | async" id="overlay">
    <mp-loading marginTop="25"></mp-loading>
  </div>     
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
readonly overlayOff$ = this.overlayService.toggleOverlay.pipe(
  pairwise(),
  map(([prev, next]) => next == null ?  !prev : next),
  startWith(true)
);
```

Also it's advised to use the changeDetectionStrategy OnPush. This is to prevent the unwanted changes the error detection might find

Comment: did not work for me.  After tweeking got it to work only once

Answer (score 0):

While I do not know why the problem happened the solution that seems to be working for me is as follows.

First in app.component.ts add the   AfterContentChecked lifecycle hook.

Create a new private variable overlayResponseHolder

Next change subscribe to

```
.subscribe(nextValue => {
    this.overlayResponseHolder = nextValue;
  });
```

create a new function ngAfterContentChecked

```
ngAfterContentChecked() {
  this.overlayOff = this.overlayResponseHolder;
}
```

Not sure if this is a solution or a kluge but now it works again.

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
<div [hidden]="overlayOff" id="overlay">
  <mp-loading marginTop="25"></mp-loading>
</div>
```

to another child component that has access to the service. That worked for me.